# CoreData preparing for eventual migration

Tags: ipad, core-data, core-data-migration

I have an ipad application that has a simple core data model with two entities. Eventually, I'll be adding a third entity in a update to the app. Is there anything I need to do with the current version of the data model to prepare for eventual migration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. In order for migration to work, you'll need to have both versions of the model inside the model at that point. (A model can contain multiple versions, one will be the *current*).